# Form's post method doesn't return to controller in Spring Securiry Login Authentication

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm following `Jérôme Jaglale`'s `Spring Cookbook`. While in spring security section I created a small login example to authenticate a user according to database.

**login.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html;  charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

    <body>
        <c:url var="loginUrl" value="/login" />
        <form action="${loginUrl}" method="post" >
            <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
                   value="${_csrf.token}"/>
            <c:if test="${param.error != null}">
                <p>
                    Invalid username and password.
                </p>
            </c:if>
            <p>
                <label for="username">Username</label>
                <input type="text" id="username" name="username"/>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input type="password" id="password"
                       name="password"/>
            </p>
            <button type="submit">Log in</button>

        </form>
        <c:url var="logout" value="/logout" /> 
        <a href="${logout}">logout</a>
    </body>
```

**LoginController.java**

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void login() {
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String processLogin() {
        return "homepage";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/logout")
    public String logout() {
        return "out"; 
    }
}
```

**SecurityConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configureUser(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
      auth.jdbcAuthentication()
                .dataSource(dataSource())
                .usersByUsernameQuery("select username,password,enabled from users where username =  ?")
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select username,authority from authorities where username =  ? ");
    }

    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
        http.formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll();
        AntPathRequestMatcher pathRequestMatcher = new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout");
        http.logout().logoutRequestMatcher(pathRequestMatcher);
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/customer");
        dataSource.setUsername("root");
        dataSource.setPassword("123");
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSourceTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        DataSourceTransactionManager transactionManager = new DataSourceTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setDataSource(dataSource());
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

And finally a folder structure to my project. 
[image: project folder sturcture]

**The database login authentication part is working perfectly** fine. 

The problem is that the form's post request doesn't return to the `LoginController`. Also the logout action doesn't return to the `/logout` mapped method in `LoginConroller`.

Please help me to figure out what went wrong in this example? 

*Thanks.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is working according with Spring Security. You don't need to implement `log in` or `log out` actions Spring Security is doing it instead of you (You just need to turn them on by `http.formLogin()`, `http.httpBasic()`, `http.logout()`, by default `log out` action is turned on).

Spring Security has filters which are making/checking some actions on request before/after hitting your controller. According to [filter pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intercepting_filter_pattern), each of such filter may check, block, process ... your request. By `http.formLogin()` or `http.logout()` you are saying to spring security to turn on filter which are responsible to `log in` or `log out` the user - so spring security will turn on the appropriate filter and if somebody is hitting the `POST /login` spring's security filter will intercept such request, log in the user and redirect him to home page (or protected requested page) and such filter will not pass your request father in the chain (to your controller) the same with `log out` action.

Spring Security giving you the options to configuring the behaviour of the filters ex. `http.formLogin().loginPage("/logpage").usernameParameter("custom-username-parameter-name")`. Of course you can turn off such filters and the requests `POST /login` `POST /logout` will hit your controller, but is not a good way, because it's implementing the same logic which are already in spring security with new bugs of course. To disable filters just do `http.formLogin().disable(); http.logout().disable();`

Comment: THANK YOU. Can I how know how to return to another page (say `homepage.jsp`) after logged in? Please.

Comment: `http.formLogin().defaultSuccessUrl("/wanter-page", true)` https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.1.5.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/AbstractAuthenticationFilterConfigurer.html#defaultSuccessUrl-java.lang.String-boolean-